# Linksys AC6000 USB - wireless networks not visible in Ubuntu 16.04 (Gnome/Unity)

Tags: drivers, gnome, usb, network-manager

I don't exactly know how to start.
I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome desktop. I've been running this for a while and everything worked perfectly until I found some issues with USB WiFi dongle. Actually issue with Ubuntu.
I have compiled the driver for my Linksys AC6000 using this page
[Driver for MT7610U Linksys AC6000](https://github.com/xtknight/mt7610u-linksys-ae6000-wifi-fixes)

First issue that I encountered is the one that when I go to the Gnome network manager (or in Unity - it doesn't matter), I can see only 802.11 b/g/n networks that are show in the neighborhood. First I thought that it is the issue with the driver, but when I used `iwpriv ra0 --all`
I was able to see all other networks 802.11 a and ac. I cannot connect to those networks using network-manager. How can I fix this issue? How can I connect to "a" standard 5GHz wireless networks?

Second issue that I found is, my other USB dongle Linksys AC1200 (WUSB6300) is working perfectly under Ubuntu 16.04. When I plug the dongle , OS automatically enable this device and I can use network manager to connect to network (a/b/g/n/ac) it doesn't matter which one. It also automatically connects to network that I used previously. When I do the same thing to my other USB dongle Linksys AC6000, Ubuntu doesn't activate this dongle by default, instead I need to use separate command to get it running.

```
sudo ifconfig ra0 up && sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart
```

without this command, the USB is good as dead...

How can I force Ubuntu to "activate" or start using USB after I plug it in?

Best regards